# Open and closed function

Tags: php, functions

I've written my first php function and I'm not too sure whether I've created it in the best way.

I want to display "our lines are open" from 9 - 5 and "our lines are closed" from 5 on wards.

Here's the code I've written.

```
<?php

 function myTest() {

 $open = "our lines are open";
 $closed = "our lines are closed";

if (time() >= strtotime("09:00:00")) {
 echo "<p>$open</p>";

if (time() >= strtotime("17:00:01"))
 echo "<p>$closed</p>";
 }
}
```

I'm also not sure how I would display this in a text field on wordpress, I've added the functions into function.php file.

Comment: I'd avoid this, what happens if somebody loads the page at 16:59:00? It'll say it's open, then when they call it'll be closed. Instead, output the actual times the lines are open, and use javascript. Also keep in mind that `time` doesn't return the time of day, it returns the time and date of day, where 0 does not equal midnight, it equals midnight on January the 1st 1970. Eitherway there is no WP involved in this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $open   = "our lines are open";
    $closed = "our lines are closed";
    if ( time() >= strtotime( '09:00:00' ) && time() <= strtotime( '17:00:00' ) ) {
        echo $open;
    } else {
        echo $closed;
    }
```

Somethinh like this should help you.

Comment: Thanks Maxim! How would I then call his function into a HTML field?

Comment: Create shordcode for this. And you will can use it anywhere. And you can create parametrs for shortcode. Like opening time, closed time, open text, closed text. And it`s will be flexible solution.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but how would I create the short code? do you know of any tutorials I could use.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API tutorial.

And your example will looks like 
`add_shortcode( 'linestatus', 'line_status_handler' );

function line_status_handler( $atts ) {
 extract( shortcode_atts( array(
  'open_time'   => '09:00:00',
  'closed_time' => '17:00:00',
  'open_text'   => 'our lines are open',
  'closed_text' => 'our lines are closed',
 ), $atts ) );

 if ( time() >= strtotime( $open_time ) && time() <= strtotime( $closed_time ) ) {
  $output = $open_text;
 } else {
  $output = $closed_text;
 }

 return $output;
}`

Comment: And usage examples:
[linestatus]
[linestatus open_time="08:00:00" closed_time="17:00:00" open_text="open" closed_text="closed"]

All params is not required.